# Passing a list to pandas loc method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I'd like to change the values of certain columns in a pandas dataframe. But I can't seem to do if I pass a list of columns inside `loc`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"ID" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
"QA_needed" : [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
"QC_needed" : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
"Report_needed" : [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
})

df.loc[:, ["QA_needed", "Report_needed"]].replace({1: "True", 0: "False"}, inplace=True)
```

To do this I have to replace the values for each column individually

```
df.loc[:, "QA_needed"].replace({1: "True", 0: "False"}, inplace=True)
df.loc[:, "QC_needed"].replace({1: "True", 0: "False"}, inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to pass the list `["QA_needed", "Report_needed"]` to the `loc` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `update`

```
df.update(df.loc[:, ["QA_needed", "Report_needed"]].replace({1: "True", 0: "False"}))
df
Out[96]: 
   ID QA_needed  QC_needed Report_needed
0   1     False          1          True
1   2      True          0          True
2   3      True          1          True
3   4     False          0         False
4   5      True          0          True
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helps a lot. Out of curiosity, why does this update method fail when inplace is set to `True`?

Comment: @Diego because update is already `inplace` check documentation

Answer (score 2):

You can also assign a boolean(`bool`):

```
df = df.assign(**df[['QA_needed','Report_needed']].astype(bool))
```

---

```
   ID  QA_needed  QC_needed  Report_needed
0   1      False          1           True
1   2       True          0           True
2   3       True          1           True
3   4      False          0          False
4   5       True          0           True
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, but I don't always need to update boolean values. Can you please explain why I would need a double asterisk here ?

Comment: @Diego since we are using as a `kwargs`: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) might be a good read to clarify